# Color perception in meditation

Tags: reference-request

In the Theravada tradition, there is a list of 38 objects of meditation. In them, there are 3 colors: Blue-Green, Yellow, Red. This is not what I'd expect if these three colors are picked in a way which is based on a basic neurological phenomena.

Can anyone point me to classical references detailing experiences and meditative observation on the nature of color observation?

Comment: I am also curious about Dukkha resulting from visual perception; any resource would be appreciated.

Comment: Aren't there four?  White is on the kasina list.  (And the Chapters 4 and 5 of Visuddhimagga details kasina practice extensively.)

Comment: @000: yes, there is also white

Answer (score 1):

The most colorful sutta is [MN77 Mahāsakuludāyisutta](https://suttacentral.net/mn77/en/sujato).

> Not perceiving form internally, someone sees visions externally, blue, with blue color, blue hue, and blue tint.
>
> Not perceiving form internally, someone sees visions externally that are yellow, with yellow color, yellow hue, and yellow tint
>
> Not perceiving form internally, someone sees visions externally that are red, with red color, red hue, and red tint.
>
> Not perceiving form internally, someone sees visions externally that are white, with white color, white hue, and white tint.
>
> (etc.)

[AN10.29](https://suttacentral.net/an10.29/en/sujato) is the second most colorful sutta.

Answer (score 1):

There is what is termed the Fire Kasina which is mentioned in the path of purification or Visuddhimagga.

There's a fascinating site where people document there experiences with many types of mental visualisations.

https://firekasina.org/about/